# Which statistical test will be useful for this dataset?

Tags: python, r, spss, hypothesis-testing

I have two independent groups of animals (**n=4 in each group**) observed under two different conditions (**A and B**) at the same time of the day and equal time interval (**12 hours**). For each group, behavioral data were recorded, divided into **7 mutually exclusive** categories of behaviour. As a result, we have a different number and frequency of categories of behavioral acts between two groups (Total: **Group A - 795** behavioural acts, **Group B - 867**).

I just visualized the total frequency of the categories in each group and the relative frequency as a percentage, but I do not know which statistical method to use with this data to determine the significance of the difference in the frequencies of behavioral acts between group A and B.

Can you suggest one?

Comment: I don't quite understand your data yet. So for every individual animal you have a count for each of the categories of behaviour, or even a time series? The animals belonging to the same group, have they been together? Does it make sense to assume them as independent of each other? The general problem here is that your effective sample size is very low with twice n=4 (it's even worse if animals in the same group are dependent of each other). It is hard to do anything with sufficient statistical power here (i.e., chance to find significance if there really is a difference).

Comment: You could treat your data as a decision tree and calculate Gini index for splits: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-build-decision-trees-aa4c09114eba

Comment: Hi, @ChristianHennig! For now I don't have time series, just total counts for each of the categories of behaviour. Yes, they been together. I understand that this is a big problem, but on some animals it is difficult to experiment and collect a sufficient sample, and you have to make a lot of assumptions. Over time, the dataset will expand, but it is necessary to conduct a primary analysis from what is, not for publication.

Comment: As for methods you could look at Poisson regression and multivariate Poisson regression and run it with a group dummy variable. However, I'd doubt that animals in the same group are independent, but if not I'm afraid chances are you can't justify any test. Surely you don't "have to make lots of assumptions" that are in fact critically violated, because then your results will be misleading. Better analyse your data visually - the significance test paradigm is under suspicion these days anyway. Of course you can try to go Bayesian if you have a good idea how to set up a prior.